# How do I decrypt a home folder from another machine using fscrypt?

Tags: encryption, home-directory, keyrings, decryption

I have 2 machines (machine1 & machine2) both running Ubuntu 18.04. Both machines use fscrypt to encrypt the home folder (using login passphrase).  If I remove the hard disk (hd1) from machine1 and plug it into machine2, how do I decrypt the home folder of machine1?

Assuming hd1 is sdb and mounted to  `/mnt/hd1/`
The following commands are run as user2 from machine2

```
>>> fscrypt status

filesystems supporting encryption: 2
filesystems with fscrypt metadata: 2

MOUNTPOINT           DEVICE       FILESYSTEM  ENCRYPTION     FSCRYPT
/                    /dev/sda2    ext4        supported      Yes
/mnt/hd1             /dev/sdb2    ext4        supported      Yes


>>> fscrypt status /mnt/hd1/
ext4 filesystem "/mnt/hd1" has 1 protector and 1 policy

PROTECTOR         LINKED  DESCRIPTION
7db5baf4xxxxxxxx  No      login protector for user1

POLICY            UNLOCKED  PROTECTORS
0000ed45xxxxxxxx  No        7db5baf4xxxxxxxx


>>> fscrypt unlock /mnt/hd1/home/user1
fscrypt unlock: user keyring not linked into session keyring

This is usually the result of a bad PAM configuration. Either correct the problem in your PAM stack, enable
pam_keyinit.so, or run "keyctl link @u @s".

>>> fscrypt unlock /mnt/hd1/home/user1 --unlock-with=/mnt/hd1:7db5baf4xxxxxxxx
fscrypt unlock: user keyring not linked into session keyring

This is usually the result of a bad PAM configuration. Either correct the problem in your PAM stack, enable
pam_keyinit.so, or run "keyctl link @u @s".
```

Must I unlock the home folder of user1 only if I am logged-in as user1? Can user2 unlock the home folder if he has user1's login passphrase? Can it be done from a different machine?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a new protector for your disk.

fscrypt has two important terms: Protectors and policies. Protectors are secrets used to protect the data. Policies are the actual key that encrypts the data. In other words, you have protectors that can open the policies that in turn decrypt the data.

On the machine1, add a new protector with the following command:
`sudo fscrypt metadata create protector /mnt/hd1`. Choose custom passphrase.

Using `fscrypt status /mnt/hd1`, look up the ids from the newly created protector and the existing policy.

Add this newly created protector to the policy with `sudo fscrypt metadata add-protector-to-policy --protector=/mnt/hd1:[protector_id] --policy=/mnt/hd1:[policy_id]` (replacing the ids with the ones you got before). Select the login and input the passphrase here.

With `fscrypt status /mnt/hd1` you should see that the policy now has the new protector. On machine2 you should be able to unlock the directory with `fscrypt unlock /mnt/hd1/home/user1`, using the newly created passphrase.

Comment: I am facing the same question. I have access to the file-system and I know the user's password, but I cannot currently boot "machine1". Is there really no way to access the data without a session on that machine?

Comment: @Hermann If you have access to the system, then you have access to the data. Login protectors are stored in `/`. In your case, assuming the root filesystem is mounted at `/mnt`, you can check the protector's id with `fscrypt status /mnt`. Then, with the protector's id, assuming your `/home/user` folder is locked, you can unlock it with `fscrypt unlock /home/user --unlock-with=/mnt:[protector_id]`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there have been some improvements. I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04, switching from kernel 4.15 to 5.15. Now all I had to do was this:

```
sudo fscrypt setup
fscrypt unlock /mnt/hd1/home/user1
```

And enter user1's password.

*Update:* I just realized that this works only if the UID of the rescuing user and the target "user1" is the same. If not, then 
[Eduardo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1241238/333867) is the way to go. The UID is stored in the protector metadata.